# C++: use std::string returned by a function: Using pointer to local variable that is out of scope

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, scope, stdstring

I've got the following function:

```cpp
MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger) {
    if (trigger) {
        std::string temporaryString = getTemporaryStringFromSomewhereElse();
        value = temporaryString.c_str();
    }
    // do processing here
    // I need `value` and `temporaryString.c_str();` to be alive and accessible here and not destroyed
 
    MyClass *object = new MyClass(value);
    object->Work();
    // etc..

}
```

So, the question is, how can I "prolong" the lifecycle of the `temporaryString` outside of the scope of the `if`-clause?

Currently, I'm getting the following error:

> Using pointer to local variable 'temporary' that is out of scope.

I understand this is related to the memory management, and the fact that the `temporary` is assumed to be "destroyed" or cleared from the memory after the `if`-clause. But I need to either prolong its life cycle, or to create another string (copy) which will have a different, wider scope.

How can I achieve this?

**Requirements:**

1. Function signature cannot change, it should remain: `MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger)`
2. I use the `value` later on to initialize another object, do some other work. I cannot have 2 variables, e.g. `value` and `anotherValueToBeUsedIfTriggerIsTrue`.

Comment: Why not simply define your string before the block and set the value inside the block?

Comment: Is there an option to completely get rid of the `temporaryString` and assign to the `vaule` directly?

Comment: If you need the information "was set inside the block" you also can use `std::optional`. This is the most readable kind of code for my point of view

Comment: That sounds interesting, could you please modify my example to show how to use it?

In practice, I just need to set the value to a new one, that's it. And it should be accessible outside of the block of course.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid anything. I'm trying to make it work. The solution I've provided as a reference doesn't work.

Comment: And why not simply returning std::string or std::optional?

Comment: @Klaus please, provide an example of "simply returning std::string or std::optional?"

Note, that the signature of the parent function cannot be changed.

Comment: You are trying to prolong the lifetime of that temp variable to the end of that function, but you have bigger problem: you are assigning that temp string to the `value` that will be accessible outside of that function!

Comment: @VladFeinstein this is exactly what I'd like to achieve.
I'd like to overwrite `value` if the `trigger` is set to true. How can I do it?

Comment: Does `MyClass` copy the contents of `value` or store the pointer?

Comment: I don't know.
It goes down to a library call with the same `const char` signagure.

Comment: Is it really that hard to overwrite a simple string variable in C++ or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at the changes in my answer...

Comment: IMHO this question should be downvoted and closed. OP changes conditions on the fly while answers coming.

Comment: @S.M. Why? I've updated my question in light of new information asked in the comments.

Comment: You got the answer in the first comment. Then you started to discuss and update the question, although the same answer in the comment is still correct, the simplest and the best, respecting all your further updates.

Comment: I was looking to understand why I had to use that solution, what are the different options. Since I've just started to learn C++, it looked weird to me that I had to keep the reference  to the `temporaryString` outside of the scope, while the `value` is already outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the declaration of the `std::string` out of the `if` block, up into the function block, eg:

```cpp
MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger) {
    std::string temporaryString;

    if (trigger) {
        temporaryString = getTemporaryStringFromSomewhereElse();
        value = temporaryString.c_str();
    }

    // do processing here
 
    MyClass *object = new MyClass(value);
    object->Work();
    // etc..

}
```

The `std::string` will be blank initially, and destroyed when the function exits, and as such the reassigned `value` will remain valid while the function is running, as long as `temporaryString` is not modified.

Comment: I ended up with this solution

Answer (score 1):

*static* storage is probably what you are searching for.
`static` attribute to a variable extends its life time to the whole program execution time.

```
void MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger) {
    if (trigger) {
        static std::string s_buffer; // Note : this line is executed only once so don't assign the value here
        s_buffer = getTemporaryStringFromSomewhereElse();
        value = s_buffer.c_str();
    }
    // use of value is still correct even outside the if statement.
}
```

Note : in case of multi threading programs use of static isn't thread safe, for this porpose the standard provides thread_local storage.

Comment: Will `static std::string s_buffer; ` be deallocated once `MyFunction` returns?

Comment: @RichardTopchii no, that is the whole point.  Being in `static` storage, the `string` will exist for the remainder of the program's lifetime.  Every call to `MyFunction` will operate on the same `string` object. This is also why the code is not thread-safe, if multiple threads call `MyFunction()` at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `std::optional` in that case as it also shows if the requested object was set or not.

Example:

```
std::string getTemporaryStringFromSomewhereElse()
{
    return "Here I am";
}

std::optional< std::string > MyFunction(bool trigger) {
    if (trigger) {
        return getTemporaryStringFromSomewhereElse();
    }   

    return std::nullopt;
}

int main()
{
    auto retval = MyFunction( true );
    if ( retval )
    {   
        std::cout << *retval << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

EDIT: ( After we got the info that the interface is not changeable )

This ends up in the question of ownership!

> Who will allocate the memory of the passed string and who is responsible to free that memory.

Options:

1. Allocate enough space and pass the pointer to that memory to the function and copy the content if trigger is set or set first char of memory to zero to show you pass back an empty string. If also an empty string is possible, use e.g. the first or last memory element as flag.
2. Allocate the memory inside the function and copy the given string and pass back the pointer  or return nullptr if trigger was not set. Caller of the function must deal with freeing the given memory.
3. If it is guaranteed that the function will *not* be called again between the first call and the usage of the content, the function itself can keep a static array and pass back the address to that static memory.

BTW: Keeping broken interfaces is a good start point for bad software :-) In the given case if also empty strings are valid, you start hacking with flags in arrays and all that broken stuff ( normally we should use structs with flags in it as already defined with std::optional ).

Comment: Please note, that the function signature cannot be changed. I need it to be `MyFunction(const char *value, bool trigger)`

Comment: @RichardTopchii This should be part of your question!

Comment: now it is, I've updated my question.

Comment: What would be the simplest / the most straightforward way to implement this? Looks like the option 1 is the easiest. The function won't be called again between the 1st call and the use of the content.

So far, I've ended extracting `temporaryString` declaration outside of the if-clause scope and it seems to have solved the issue, although the code is not very elegant.